# Windows Phone 8 - Pass data from a textbox to a textblock on another page

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

So here is my simple Windows Phone 8 problem: I have a TextBox at page1 and there I type in: "50".

Now on page2 I want to divide my value 50 by 2 so and want to display the result "25" (hope I calculated it right ;)

How can I do this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Page1.xaml.cs

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml?myNumber=" + TextBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
        }

Page2.xaml.cs

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string QueryStr = "";
            NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("myNumber",out QueryStr);
            TextBlock1.text = ((int.Parse(QueryStr)) / 2).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you navigating to the second page after the first page, if so send the value as a parameter in the navigation. I.e

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml?myNumber=" + myValue, UriKind.Relative));
```

Obviously the 'myValue' needs to be replaces for a variable with your value in it and then you can retreive the value on the onNavigatedTo event in Page2 like so.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var number = NavigationContext.QueryString["myNumber"];
}
```

Comment: Did this help, or did I misunderstand what you were attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution - instead of passing the variable you may make it *static*, so it will be available through the whole app, or save in *PhoneState*. A simple solution along with binding can look like this:

In XAML - TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxValue, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="Number" Width="50"/>
```

In code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void RaiseProperty(string name) { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); }

    public static int globalValue = 0; // your global value
    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get { return globalValue.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(value, out globalValue)) globalValue = 0; // some check-up if number is not valid
            RaiseProperty("TextBoxValue"); // update textbox
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this; // here or in XAML
    }
}
```

Then anywhere you can access your variable:

```
int a = MainPage.globalValue / 2;
```